# I am God. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the initiator of this riddle
>   I am the beginning of everything
>   I am the origin of god
>   But not long ago god was the origin of me
>   In some way I am god
>   And even god is stranded without me
>   I live even if you kill my body
>   you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back
>   I can be the greatest thing in your life
>   Or destroy everything you love

And one last thing:

> You will need me to find the answer

Comment: is it "idea"?..

Comment: I suppose saying "You are God" isn't exact enough? :-P

Comment: @nbar is it Soul like mentioned in the Bhagavad Gita

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be

> Thought/idea(s)

I am the initiator of this riddle

> Thought/ideas create riddles (usually and hopefully :) )

I am the beginning of everything

> All creations first start with thought/ideas. Also, thought focused on by many creates thought-form, which eventually creates matter (according to New Age, "Law of Attraction" teachings)

I am the origin of god
But not long ago god was the origin of me

> Thought created the concept of God, but God ("All-that-Is") thought, which created more thought.

In some way I am god
And even god is stranded without me

> Thought is god because, in a practical sense, "We are what we think." Without thought, there is no concept of god.

I live even if you kill my body
you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back

> Ideas turn to ideals, and can live on long after the original thinker is gone.

I can be the greatest thing in your life
Or destroy everything you love

> People live for ideas/ideals, and they can be crushed by either their own ideas or their (or other peoples') societies' ideals

Answer (score 9):

is it

> The mind

I am the initiator of this riddle

> The mind is the one who came up with the riddle

I am the beginning of everything

> when he is created, your existence begins

I am the origin of god

> The mind came up with the concept of god

But not long ago god was the origin of me

> god made the mind

In some way I am god

> it controls how you perceive reality

And even god is stranded without me

> without it, our concept of him would not exist

I live even if you kill my body

> ideas live on even if the person doesn't

you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back

> once again its about ideas, because you can kill the wielder

I can be the greatest thing in your life

> The mind is a wonderful thing

Or destroy everything you love

> The mind can play horrible games on you

You will need me to find the answer

> self explanatory, you need your mind answer this riddle

Comment: That was my idea too, but I couldn't make it fit all the lines. +1

Comment: Really close, and would like to accept. But it's not the mind itself. (2 Questions that doesnt fit with mind, and you toke there the right answer)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

> Imagination

I am the initiator of this riddle

> You used your imagination to make this riddle

I am the beginning of everything

> Everything that is created starts with someone's imagination (inventions, etc.)

I am the origin of god

> The idea of god came from people's imagination

But not long ago god was the origin of me

> God created people with imaginations

In some way I am god

> Same idea as "origin of god"

And even god is stranded without me

> Same idea as "origin of god"

I live even if you kill my body

> Really not sure with this

you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back

> You can stop someone's imagination temporarily but they could still be imaginative later

I can be the greatest thing in your life

> Being very imaginative can be great for your life.

Or destroy everything you love

> Imagination can cause denial/hallucinations which ruin your life.

You will need me to find the answer

> You need your imagination to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

is it:

> energy?
>
> everything consist of energy...energy makes him narrate>> am the initiator of this riddle
>
> energy was from the begning, it just converted into types>>I am the beginning of everything energy itsef is a kind of god>> I am the origin of god

But not long ago god was the origin of me
In some way I am god
And even god is stranded without me

> energy just kind of leave our body and stay some where for eve>>>I live even if you kill my body you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back I can be the greatest thing in your life>> greatest thing in life having a enegy in heat to do work , to do anything..Or destroy everything you love And one last thing:

You will need me to find the answer

> we need energy to find the answer

Comment: Welcom jatin2302 to Puzzling! I have edited your answer to include spoilers tags ">!" to cover you answer and prevent it from possibly spoiling it for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ...

> Confidence ?

I am the initiator of this riddle

> Through the confidence you can put this as puzzle

I am the beginning of everything

> It is necessary thing to start anything

I am the origin of god

> Not sure about this line..

But not long ago god was the origin of me

> obviously god is not origin of confidence

In some way I am god

> Not Sure

And even god is stranded without me

> Not Sure

I live even if you kill my body

> Confidence is stay as it is.

you can kill me! But never be sure I don't come back

> If confidence kill by someone or our self so not sure that it will come back

I can be the greatest thing in your life

> yes it is

Or destroy everything you love

> May be it happen with lack of confidence.